# java: cannot find symbol when using try/catch

Tags: java

I'm trying to collect input from the user, then if it's numeric – to turn it into an int, and if it's not – ask him to enter a numeric input

I'm using try/catch for this:

```
            System.out.println("Col: ");
            String temporary_col = sc.nextLine();

            try {
                int col = Integer.parseInt(temporary_col) - 1;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number");
                int col = sc.nextInt() - 1;
            }
```

and after that when I'm trying to use those variables:

```
field[col] = "X";
```

it returns this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
```

Answer (score 1):

`col` is only visible in the block where you declare it. In your current code, you have 2 variables called `col`, one in the `try` block and one in the `catch` block. To fix this, declare the variable outside of the 2 blocks:

```
int col;
try {
  col = Integer.parseInt(temporary_col) - 1;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("Please enter a number");
  col = sc.nextInt() - 1;
}
```

Comment: I did it and it entered the catch section at the beginning of the code, like this: 
``` 

Enter #1 barrier location (row, col)
Row: 
Please enter a number
``` 

and if I'll enter a string it will crash

Comment: a "while" loop is your friend.